# Finding density function for a given distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function 
$$
\\ F_X(t)=\begin{cases}      0, & t<0 \\ 2/11, & 0\leqslant  t<1 \\7/11, & 1 \leqslant  t<2 \\1, & 2 \leqslant  t  \end{cases} \
$$
Find the density function of $X$.

I know that the density is 
$$
\\   f_X(t)=\begin{cases}   0, &t\notin\{0,1,2\} \\2/11, &t=0 \\ 5/11, &t=1 \\ 4/11, & t=2  \end{cases}    \
$$

but I don't know how or why this solution is true, hope for an explanation.

Comment: It simply reduces to $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)=\int_{-\infty}^t f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and we interpret this integral as a sum, when the distribution is discrete

Comment: @Fakemistake But if one changes a finite number of points in a function then the integral stays the same, and I can redefine $f_X(0)=f_X(1)=f_X(2)=0$ and get that the integral equals $0\ne F_X(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a sketch of the cdf. The distance between the circles and the red bullets show the jump of the cdf from $t-\epsilon$ to $t$ where $t=0,1,2$ and $\epsilon\to 0$.

At a cdf the horicontal lines shows that the pdf is $0$ at that interval. I hope the sketch make it easier to understand the connection of the cdf and the pdf here. Feel free to ask, if something is still not comprehensible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What I don't understand is the fact that if I change a finite number of points in any finction $f$ (and let $f'$ be the new function after I changed the points) then $\int f(x) dx= \int f'(x) dx$. In our case, I can redefine the points $f_X(0):=f_X(1):=f_X(2):=0$, thus, the redefined function $f_X\equiv 0$, thus $\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(s)ds=0\ne F_X(t)$ which doesn't settle with the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(s)ds=F_X(t)$$.

Comment: @J.Doe If $\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(s)ds=0\ \forall \ \ t\in \mathbb R$ then  your redefined  pdf $f_X(s)$ is not valid. One property for a valid pdf is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(s)ds=1$. Thus there is no surprise that an ill-defined function does not fulfill other necessary properties.